# Selectize Laravel Form Edit

Tags: jquery, forms, laravel, selectize.js

I followed this tutorial [here](https://laravel-news.com/2015/10/how-to-add-tagging-to-your-laravel-app/) to use selectize and rtconnor tagging in my project and it works great when I create a new ticket, but I can't get it work when I try to edit a ticket.

In my TicketController edit()

```
$tags = Ticket::with('tagged')->first();
```

I get all tags that are tagged to this ticket.

In my view I have the this text field:

```
<input type="text" name="tags" class="form-control" id="tags" value='@foreach ($ticket->tags as $tag) {{$tag->name}} @endforeach'>
```

And this is my script:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#tags').selectize({
            plugins: ['remove_button'],
            delimiter: ',',
            persist: false,
            valueField: 'tag',
            labelField: 'tag',
            searchField: 'tag',
            options: tags,
            create: function(input) {
                return {
                    tag: input
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    var tags = [
            @foreach ($tags as $tag)
            {tag: "{{$tag}}" },
        @endforeach
    ];
</script>
```

The Textfield is empty, but when I remove the id="tags" I can see my tags but only as a plain text field and not as selectize.

I think the problem is my script. Can you help me?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not real familiar with the selectize plugin but looks like the value attribute needs to be comma separated. try calling the implode function on your tags like this..

```
<input type="text" name="tags" class="form-control" id="tags" value="{{ implode(',', $ticket->tags) }}" />
```

not sure if that will work... try that.

edit: oup! also noticed in your tags variable... the foreach loop will result in a trailing comma which might cause problems. I would remove it.